# PHP: How to constantly add to a database

Tags: php

I'll be constantly adding stock prices into a database,
But what "settings/variables" do I put into the database to allow it to accept multiple values for a field? 
So later I can echo the SQL Database out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do this in the exact way you're asking. Multiple values in a single field is bad form and makes for an unmanageable system. You should have one row for each column-value pair that you have. Ex:

```
Stock     Price     Date
AAPL      5.00      2016-04-25
AAPL      6.00      2016-04-26
AAPL      7.00      2016-04-27
```

This way, you can always `SELECT Price, MAX(DATE) FROM xxx WHERE Stock = 'AAPL'` and get the latest price, but can still use something like `SELECT Price FROM xxx WHERE Stock = 'AAPL' ORDER BY Date` and get a clean list of your stock history for this particular ticker.